# Generic method for obtaining enum items in an ushort object

Tags: c#, generics, enum

The idea is to perform a bit-wise scan of an `ushort` provided to **find any and all matches** within an `enum collection`.

The code I developed is as follows:

```
public List<T> GetEnumItemsFromUshort<T>(ushort input) where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable
    {
        var output = new List<T>();
        foreach (T enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            if ((input & enumValue.ToUInt16(new CultureInfo("en-US"))) == enumValue.ToUInt16(new CultureInfo("en-US")))
            {
                output.Add(enumValue);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

As you can see, I use a generic type to define the return type.

I searched the site and found that constraining the generic type with the following `struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable`, makes it behave like an `enum`.

The code generates a list of the enum provided to contains the matches found.

Then it proceeds to scan the input value to find any and all items that masked (a bit-wise operation as stated before) do match.

If a match is found it adds the enum case to the return list.

I want to know whether this is a good or bad implementation and ways to make it better, it performs as expected but I feel like there's room for optimization.

To provide an example, suppose the following enum and input:

```
public ushort sample = 6;

public enum SampleCases
{
    Case1 = 0x1,
    Case2 = 0x2,
    Case3 = 0x4,        
    Case4 = 0x8,
}
```

The output for this code would be a List of type SampleCases with 2 items, Case2 and Case 3 since both (bit-wise) are contained in the sample provided. Tell me if this works as an example for you.

Comment: Can you post an example with the desired output? It sounds to me as you're trying to implement `SomeEnum x = (SomeEnum)input;`

Comment: I posted an edit, tell me whether this works for you as an example

Comment: What do you intend to use this list for?

Comment: I intend to use this list to retrieve any and all buttons pressed on a device, since it returns the information in a bit-wise fashion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code can be greatly simplified but first I'd list few things:

1) If your enum is a bitmap then you should mark it with `[Flags]`.

```
[Flags]
public enum SampleCases
{
    Case1 = 0x1,
    Case2 = 0x2,
    Case3 = 0x4,        
    Case4 = 0x8,
}
```

2) you shouldn't convert an `enum` value to `ushort`, `enum`s default type is `int` and for `[Flags]` you may (easily?) run out of bits. If value is out of `ushort` range (your input) simply drop it, `Convert.ToInt16()` will throw `OverflowException` for out of range values.

3) You shouldn't create a new instance of `CultureInfo` every time you need it. It may be expansive. Moreover you're using *en-US* culture, you already have the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

3) To know if a value is valid you can use `Enum.IsDefined()`.

To put all together:

```
public List<T> GetEnumItemsFromUshort<T>(ushort input)
    where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable
{
    const int bitsInUInt16 = sizeof(ushort) * 8;

    return Enumerable.Range(0, bitsInUInt16 - 1)
        .Select(x => 1 << x)
        .Where(x => (input & x) == x && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), x))
        .Select(x => (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T)))
        .ToList();
}
```

It's a minor change and a micro-optimization but I'd also change return type to `IEnumerable<T>`. If caller will need a list then it will be able to call `ToList()` itself and if it does not need it then you will avoid an unnecessary copy. Also first `Select()` may be dropped and embedded in `Where()` clause.

Note that 0 is not handled, you may want to include it or not; I'd leave it out because it's *always* matched unless you have `input == 0`. Note that to do not have a 0 default value for an `enum` is a dangerous practice, value types are 0 initialized and an uninitialized `enum` will have an *unknown* value.

Inverting point of view you may write:

```
public List<T> GetEnumItemsFromUshort<T>(ushort input)
    where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<object>()
        .Where(x => ((ushort)x & input) == (ushort)x)
        .Cast<T>()
        .ToList();
}
```

This 2nd version will also handle *shared* bits like `GuestDefault`, `UserDefault` and `AdminDefault` in this example:

```
[Flags]
enum SampleCases {
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Execute = 4,
    GuestDefault = Read,
    UserDefault = Read | Execute,
    AdminDefault = Read | Write | Execute
}
```

Note the *hacky* `.Cast<object>()` to use `.Where()` over a non-generic enumeration (also paying boxing price). Here **I tried to keep code short but I wouldn't implement this with LINQ** (generated enumerator with `yield return` will be more clear, IMO). Also this code returns duplicates and aliases, if it's not what you want then you have to handle them (checking for distinct values and for multiple bits set on the same value).

Very last point: your constraints for generic parameter reduce wrong usage of your function but it doesn't really limit usage to enums: most primitive types implement same interfaces. I'd also add an explicit check:

```
if (!typeof(T).IsEnum))
    throw new ArgumentException("Template argument must be an enum type.");
```

Comment: I see you are not using the input anywhere in your code, thus returning a list of bit values, this does not meet the same objective as my code, since I want to retrieve which flags are present in the input.

I think I am not understanding the code you wrote.

Comment: @OscarGuillamon you're right, I missed out first Where()! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I will try it ASAP, but it now meets the same purpose as mine, marked as solution, thanks for the tips.  Will keep them in mind from now on

Comment: I don't quite understand the second iteration in which you say _inverting point of view you may write_ what is the point of `Cast<object>` and then recasting to the generic type?

Comment: Casting to object is just an ugly hack because LINQ methods don't works on non-generic enumerations then I have to cast to object (paying boxing price) and then use it with Where(). If you write your own non-generic Where() or you use a plain foreach then you won't need it.

Comment: Also note that the point of this code is to prevent the second enum you wrote, the one that combines other cases, as it can get awfully long to type all the cases that can exist. Just want to figure out which keys were pressed (the point of this code is to retrieve a list of all keys pressed)

Comment: @OscarGuillamon OK, if it's what you want to avoid then...ignore it! ;)

Comment: Your help has been much appreciated, we found out we can use this for any enuenum (error codes, outputs activated, etc) thanks a lot for your help again!

Comment: Why don't you just use `sizeof(int)` instead of the size of short * 8?

Comment: Size of int is 4, we enumerate bits: size of ushort * bits per byte = 2 * 8 = 16 bit. Anyway in this case also a magic number isn't such bad...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I have a question upon checking the code.

What is the point of the Enum.IsDefined(enumType, x) ??? 

To check whether the bit you are comparing exists in the given enumerator?

If so, is there a way to extract and compare only the cases which the enumerator comprehends? I feel like there is some operations done that are not necessary at all.

Not saying your code is bad, just checking if I understand correctly the code, excuse me if this offends you.

Comment: @OscarGuillamon LOL don't worry, I'm not so sensible, posting code I'm open to peer review, criticisms and suggestions! Usually they're an unique way to learn.

Comment: Back to the point: with Enum.IsDefined() yes, you check if a value is defined for that particular enum. You can start from available values (instead of checking for all) but then you'll have duplicates (see _deleted_ code) if your flag have _aliases_ (see again deleted code). Of course it may be avoided checking, for each candidate value, if it's already used or if it has multiple bits set. From my POV (of course questionable!) it increases complexity without any measurable performance gain (vs 32 bit enumeration).

Comment: You may try resorting deleted code, dropping LINQ for a plain enumeration and adding code to handle aliases and multibit flags. With yield return it should be straight to implement. It _shouldn't_ (but guesses are...guesses) be faster than the other version and it will handle same things. About clarity, well it should be more clear because at first sight you'll understand what it is doing (even if it's longer), that's why I used a long name for constant bitsInUInt16...it's an hint to understand what code will do (enumerate through all UInt32 bits).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yeah, you are right, it's just that I want to understand to improve my code analysis.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I found an exception in the behaviour of the code and, trying to fix it I came up with this iteration which does not give an exception and works, can you give me your opinion on it? here is the line of code I modified  
`.Where(x => (input & x) == x && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), x))`  

The exception I found occurs whenever I have more than one key pressed I don't come to understand why.

Comment: You're right! Use of underlying type was there from _version_ with Convert.ChangeType() but it's wrong now, Enum.IsDefined() needs true enum type not underlying type! I'll fix it, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31750/discussion-between-oscar-guillamon-and-adriano-repetti).